# How to expand an element (img) without the header expanding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

As the title explains, I have an img element containing a logo contained by a header element. I want to have the image expand when you hover over it, or possibly just have a pulse type effect, but for simplicity I'm starting with just having it expand by hovering over it. I have an idea of how to do this by increasing the max-width and applying a transition ease to it.

But most importantly I am trying to figure out how to get the img element to expand without the header expanding. How can I do this? The code is below.

Note if it makes any difference, I am running Bootstrap 4.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
/* background-color: #393939*/
 background: url("../Images/background.jpg") repeat;
}



/*

-=-=- NAVIGATION BAR -=-=-

*/
#header-nav {
 background-color: #262626;
 font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.grid-container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-container > a {
 text-align: center;
}

.navlink {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #C9C9C9;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 background:
  linear-gradient(white, white)
  bottom
  /100% 0px
  no-repeat;
 transition: 0.2s all;
}

.navlink:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-size: 100% 4px;
}

.active {
 color: #FFF;
}



/*

-=-=- HEADING BANNER -=-=-

*/

header {
 background: url("https://i.imgur.com/CYyE6bN.png") center;
 border-bottom: thick solid #461F66;
}

.heading-banner {
 max-width: 75%;
 padding: 5%;
 filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 20px #000);
}

.heading-banner:hover {
 max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

  <!-- Meta & Other -->
  <title>Infamous | Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Infamous official website">
  <meta name="keywords" content ="Infamous, Minecraft, Server, Game, Gaming">
  <meta name="author" content="MrWardy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Stylesheets/default.css">
  
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35fad75205.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
 

 </head>



 <body>

  <header>
   <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="container grid-container">
     <a class="active navlink" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="#rules"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Rules</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="#vote"><i class="fas fa-star"></i> Vote</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="#store"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Store</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="https://discord.gg/ZnN3f4P" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i> Discord</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFvs3IZNgziCe0WARpJpYVw" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i> YouTube</a>
    </div>
   </nav>
<!--
   <div id="heading">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="./Images/rome.png" alt="Minecraft Screenshot">
   </div>
-->
   <img class="heading-banner mx-auto d-block" src="https://i.imgur.com/0h5g3bd.png" alt="Infamous banner">
  </header>

  <!-- JavsScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
/* background-color: #393939*/
 background: url("../Images/background.jpg") repeat;
}



/*

-=-=- NAVIGATION BAR -=-=-

*/
#header-nav {
 background-color: #262626;
 font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.grid-container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-container > a {
 text-align: center;
}

.navlink {
 display: inline-block;
 color: #C9C9C9;
 padding: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 background:
  linear-gradient(white, white)
  bottom
  /100% 0px
  no-repeat;
 transition: 0.2s all;
   
}

.navlink:hover {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-size: 100% 4px;
    
}

.active {
 color: #FFF;
}



/*

-=-=- HEADING BANNER -=-=-

*/

header {
   height: 90vh; 
 background: url("https://i.imgur.com/CYyE6bN.png") center;
 border-bottom: thick solid #461F66;
}


.heading-banner {
 max-width: 75%;
 padding: 5%;
 filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 20px #000);
    z-index: 9;
}

.heading-banner:hover {
 max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <head>

  <!-- Meta & Other -->
  <title>Infamous | Home</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Infamous official website">
  <meta name="keywords" content ="Infamous, Minecraft, Server, Game, Gaming">
  <meta name="author" content="MrWardy">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Stylesheets/default.css">
  
  <!-- Fonts -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/35fad75205.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 
 

 </head>



 <body>

  <header>
   <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar-nav">
    <div class="container grid-container">
     <a class="active navlink" href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="#rules"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Rules</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="#vote"><i class="fas fa-star"></i> Vote</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="#store"><i class="fas fa-tags"></i> Store</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="https://discord.gg/ZnN3f4P" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i> Discord</a>
     <a class="navlink" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFvs3IZNgziCe0WARpJpYVw" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i> YouTube</a>
    </div>
   </nav>
<!--
   <div id="heading">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="./Images/rome.png" alt="Minecraft Screenshot">
   </div>
-->
  
<img class="heading-banner mx-auto d-block" src="https://i.imgur.com/0h5g3bd.png" alt="Infamous banner">

  </header>

  <!-- JavsScript -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </body>

</html>
```

I add a height value to header, you can set the height you want

Comment: Please run the example in "full page"

Comment: That does work, there's just one issue and that is it makes the header no longer responsive which is very important to my site, when I used both pixels or vh, is there something else I can do to make sure it remains responsive?

Comment: if you use bootstrap i recommend you use the grid system, and use a div .container .row, and col-md-x, and the <a> tag inside div col-sd-x or col-xl-x (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) if you need more help, please tell me

Comment: Yeah, thank you for offering your help, I added .container .row and .col-md-12 to a div element surrounding the entire header element but that didn't exactly do what I was expecting. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/VhptgFK.jpg) of the website. Here is a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/4CwWi9nR) of my updated code. I am new to bootstrap so I have a very basic understanding of it, CSS has never been my strong suit to begin with.